# libfreetype.6.dylib incompatible

Tags: php, macos, osx-mavericks, x11, mnpp

I get the following error when I run MNPP, which is a like XAMPP/MAMP but with Nginx instead of Apache.

```
$ sudo mnpp --php53 --start
-n Starting php-fpm 
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libfontconfig.1.dylib requires version 17.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 14.0.0
/Applications/MNPP/init/php.sh: line 95: 44087 Trace/BPT trap: 5       $php_fpm_BIN $php_opts
 failed
```

Judging from all the SO threads on this topic, I'm pretty sure this is a X11/XQuartz Mac OSX Mavericks issue as it this command works on my previous Mac with 10.7.5.

How do I upgrade my version of libfreetype.6.dylib?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable set.  Don't do that.